# Mulitple Events, One handler called one time

Tags: c#, events, eventhandler

TL;DR: Can I make a handler that is attached to many events fire only once, even when I know all of the events will be fired?

I'm trying to listen to a collection of objects, each of which will complete a specific task and then notify the owner that it is completed. To do this I've  simply looped over the collection and added an event handler to each object

```
foreach(var obj in collection)
{ 
  obj.Event += GroupHandler;
}
```

and that works fine. However since I know the tasks will complete around the same time, and since it really doesn't matter if I queue a bit early I'd like to have a way to ensure that once GroupHandler is raised, it won't be raised again for the current execution set so I could do something like:

```
private void GroupHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(var obj in collection)
   {
     obj.QueueNext();
   }
}
```

Ideally I'd end up with something like

```
private void GroupHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(GroupHandler.HasRun) return;

   foreach(var obj in collection)
   {
     obj.QueueNext();
   }
}
```

I know that I could use some global bool (or more likely an int to track cycles) but I don't like that as a solution. I'm looking for something a bit nicer than that.

Comment: Detach the event from the objects at the first call.

Comment: But I'd like them to be raised again at a later time. Likely 15-20 seconds down the road

Comment: Then reattach them, but I belive you're overlooking the problem, if you don't care which one of the objects is the finished then just attach to one of the objects event.

Comment: I'd go with that if there was a clean and clear place to reattach, and though I don't care which object is finished, there isn't really an explicit guarantee that they're all running all the time, but I guess I could force it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working with what Gusman mentioned in the comments an removed the event handlers. The real key though was finding out where to reattach them. So I ended up passing the handler function in the QueueNext call.

Code looks like this

```
private void GroupHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach(var obj in collection)
   {
     obj.Event -= GroupHandler;
   }

   foreach(var obj in collection)
   {
     obj.QueueNext(GroupHandler);
   }
}
```

and QueueNext looks like

```
public void QueueNext(EventHandler nextHandler)
{
   this.Event += nextHandler
   QueueNext();
}
```

this way the event is only called once, and will be called for each set of execution.

Answer (score 0):

As Gusman said in comments, you can have just one of the objects fire off the event. That way you know it executes only once per event set.

Alternatively, you could set up a Timer, a counter and a flag. Set the flag on the first event execution and then start the timer. As long as the flag is set, ignore the rest of the events. Set your counter to the number of objects you're tracking and decrement the counter as each one fires off its event. When either the timer expires or the counter reaches zero, reset the flag, reset the counter and cancel the timer. This could rapidly get complicated and may have a bunch of corner cases, so if you don't care too much about timing, then the first method is much better. Simplify as much as possible.

Comment: You aren't wrong about it getting complicated, I tried something similar to that, and it swiftly got ugly. As for only having one of the objects fire the event, its how I'm currently getting around it, but I'd like a better way. The problem with only one firing is that it forces the assumption that the attached object be running constantly, which isn't hard to implement, but isn't exactly the design I'm going for.

Comment: What defines the boundaries of an "event set" ? That will dictate the sorts of solutions available. If it's that each object fires off at least once, then a counter might work best. If it's time bound, then stick with a timer. There's a huge number of options here. Pick the simplest and most easily maintained method.